# Python regex - cleaning markdown html

Tags: python, regex, markdown

I'm trying to figure out a good way to sanitize / reformat User Generated Content that is written in the Markdown format.  I want to 'correct' improper content (as best as possible).

For now I'm sticking to HTML comments ( though I'd appreciate any embedded HTML ).

The markdown format requires any embedded HTML to appear within it's own lines.

Bad (input):

```
one
<!-- two -->
three
four
five <!-- five.point.five -->
six
```

Good (output):

```
one

<!-- two -->

three
four
five

<!-- five.point.five -->

six
```

Comment: Just to add... the only solution i've come up with ( which sort of works ) is one that pulls out the comment + a character before/after; then tries to reassemble the line.  It's ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
re.sub(r'\s*(<!--(?:[^-]+|-(?!->))*-->)\s*', '\\n\\n\\1\\n\\n', yourstring)
```

Comment: `\s*` -- ARGH!  I've been playing with lookahead/lookbehind and examining the string for 2 hours.  what a simple and elegant (AND BETTER) approach.  Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To convert the first output to the second you would replace `<!--` with `\r\n<!--` and `-->` with `-->\r\n`, or whatever newline character, or constant, is equivalent to `\r\n`. You could do this with `replace()`, probably not requiring regex. [ `\r` is not really necessary.]

You seem to suggest that you are doing this already, so perhaps there is more to your question.

Comment: The answer from Casimir addressed my concern.  I was doing way too much work examining the strings to ensure I only get 1 line.  An outright `replace` like you suggest would create 2 newlines when one is already specified -- a user may have written 3 codes properly but 3 codes improperly.